# How do I rotate all or specific pages in a PDF using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf, fpdi

I have PDF documents uploaded by users that need to be processed by auditors. Sometimes the scanned pages in a PDF are sideways or upside down. How do I rotate the pages using php?

I'm using TCPDF and TCPDI, which I believe are the same as fpdf/fpdi

My code, below, will rotate all pages just fine, but when I specify just one page, let's say page 3 of 5. It will leave pages 1 and 2 alone, rotate page 3 and will continue to rotate page 4 and 5. Why?

Also, does this code make sense? Is this the proper way to do this or is there an easier way?

```
function rotatePDF($file, $degrees, $page = 'all'){

    $pdf = new TCPDI(); // new object
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false); // no headers
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false); // no footers

    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file); //the original file

    // rotate all - THIS WORKS FINE
    if($page=="all"){
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) { 
            $pageformat = array('Rotate'=>$degrees);

            $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
            $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpage);

            // get original page orientation        
            $orientation = $size['w'] > $size['h'] ? 'L' : 'P';

            $pdf->AddPage($orientation,$pageformat);
            $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);      
        }
    }else{
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
            if($page == $i){
                $pageformat = array('Rotate'=>$degrees);

                $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
                $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpage);

                // get original page orientation
                $orientation = $size['w'] > $size['h'] ? 'L' : 'P';

                $pdf->AddPage($orientation,$pageformat);
                $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);                      
            }else{      
                $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);

                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);                      
            }
        }
    }
    $out = realpath($file);

    if(rename($file,"files/1/file.bak")){
        $result = $pdf->Output($out, "F"); 
        if($result == "" ){
            echo "ok";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Failed to rename old PDF";
        die;
    }
}

$file = "files/1/1.pdf";
rotatePDF($file,90); // rotating all works fine
rotatePDF($file,90,3); // rotates page 3 AND all following
```

Comment: PDF's have a lot of things in them that carry from one page to the other. Rotation clearly is one of them. You must rotate back when you want the next page not rotated.

Answer (score 2):

After many trial and error rotations I figured it out. Here's the code:

```
function rotatePDF($file, $degrees, $page = 'all'){

    $pdf = new TCPDI(); 
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);

    // rotate each page
    if($page=="all"){
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) { 
            $pageformat = array('Rotate'=>$degrees);
            $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
            $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpage);
            //$info = $pdf->getPageDimensions();
            $orientation = $size['w'] > $size['h'] ? 'L' : 'P';

            $pdf->AddPage($orientation,$pageformat);
            $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);      
        }
    }else{
        $rotateFlag = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) { 
            if($page == $i){
                $pageformat = array('Rotate'=>$degrees);
                $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
                $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpage);
                //$info = $pdf->getPageDimensions();
                $orientation = $size['w'] > $size['h'] ? 'L' : 'P';

                $pdf->AddPage($orientation,$pageformat);
                $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);
                $rotateFlag = 1;
            }else{
                if($rotateFlag==1){
                    // page after rotation; restore rotation
                    $rotateFlag = 0;
                    $pageformat = array('Rotate'=>0);

                    $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
                    $pdf->AddPage($orientation,$pageformat);
                    $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);
                }else{
                    // pages before rotation and after restoring rotation
                    $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
                    $pdf->AddPage();
                    $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $out = realpath($file);

    if(rename($file,"files/1/file.bak")){
        $result = $pdf->Output($out, "F"); 
        if($result == "" ){
            echo "ok";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Failed to rename old PDF";
        die;
    }
}

$file = "files/1/1.pdf";
rotatePDF($file,90); // rotating all works fine
rotatePDF($file,180,3); // rotates only page 3
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add "'Rotate' => $degrees" in my code. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Could you please tell or share the code that how did you use TCPDF and TCPDI

Comment: I know it has been 5 years, but this is absolute gold!